# merging two arrays and keep duplicate values

Tags: php

Is there a php function to merge 2 arrays and keep duplicates?

Like:

```
$a=array('a','b','c');
$b=array('b','c','b');
array_merge2($a,$b);
//result: array('a','b','c','b','c','b');
```

thanks

add1:

what the... i previously tested array_merge and it didn't keep duplicate values =/

Comment: array_merge() won't keep values with duplicate keys iff the entries are associative. It will merge cleanly if the keys are numeric

Comment: If you have associative arrays and have no need for the current keys in the array, you can call `array_values` on both arrays before merging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`array_merge` keeps the duplicates.

http://codepad.org/XGcMAi3z

Answer (score 2):

In the examples for [array_splice](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php) it shows how to add the contents of one array onto the end of another.  Just replace the last parameter with your array.

```
array_splice($input, count($input), 0, array($x, $y));
```

So in your example:

```
$a=array('a','b','c');
$b=array('b','c','b');
array_splice($a, count($a), 0, $b);
```