# Combine two array of data

Tags: php, arrays

I want to combine two array where each have the same index ( ID  here ) , but I dont want to delete duplicate ID 
( Sorry for my english ... )

```
First array name :   $data['student']
Second array name:  $data_student_name
```

I have this array (  `$data['student']` )

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 16 [groups_id] => 1 [group_number] => 301 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 17 [groups_id] => 1 [group_number] => 301 ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 18 [groups_id] => 1 [group_number] => 301 ) [3] => Array ( [id] => 5 [groups_id] => 1 [group_number] => 301 ) [4] => Array ( [id] => 14 [groups_id] => 1 [group_number] => 301 ) [5] => Array ( [id] => 18 [groups_id] => 2 [group_number] => 434 ) [6] => Array ( [id] => 19 [groups_id] => 2 [group_number] => 434 ) [7] => Array ( [id] => 19 [groups_id] => 1 [group_number] => 301 ) )
```

and this array  `$data_student_name`

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 5 [firstname] => Bruno [sex] => M ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 14 [firstname] => David [sex] => M ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 16 [firstname] => Élyse [sex] => F ) [3] => Array ( [id] => 17 [firstname] => Jean [sex] => M ) [4] => Array ( [id] => 18 [firstname] => Julie [sex] => F ) [5] => Array ( [id] => 19 [firstname] => Marie [sex] => F ) )
```

I combine my two array  with this

```
  $data['group_student']= array(); 
    foreach ($data_student_name as $arr) { 
        $match = false; 
        foreach ($data['student'] as $arr2) { 
            if ($arr['id'] == $arr2['id']) { 
               $match = true; 
               $data['group_student'][] = array_merge($arr, $arr2); 
               break; 
            } 
        } 
        if ( !$match ) $data['group_student'][] = $arr; 
    }
```

And I optain  this  result  ( Marie is not duplicated :( ) (  `$data['group_student']` )

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 5 [firstname] => Bruno [sex] => M [groups_id] => 1 [group_number] => 301 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 14 [firstname] => David [sex] => M [groups_id] => 1 [group_number] => 301 ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 16 [firstname] => Élyse [sex] => F [groups_id] => 1 [group_number] => 301 ) [3] => Array ( [id] => 17 [firstname] => Jean [sex] => M [groups_id] => 1 [group_number] => 301 ) [4] => Array ( [id] => 18 [firstname] => Julie [sex] => F [groups_id] => 1 [group_number] => 301 ) [5] => Array ( [id] => 19 [firstname] => Marie [sex] => F [groups_id] => 2 [group_number] => 434 )  1 ))
```

and I want this result ( Marie is duplicated )

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 5 [firstname] => Bruno [sex] => M [groups_id] => 1 [group_number] => 301 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 14 [firstname] => David [sex] => M [groups_id] => 1 [group_number] => 301 ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 16 [firstname] => Élyse [sex] => F [groups_id] => 1 [group_number] => 301 ) [3] => Array ( [id] => 17 [firstname] => Jean [sex] => M [groups_id] => 1 [group_number] => 301 ) [4] => Array ( [id] => 18 [firstname] => Julie [sex] => F [groups_id] => 1 [group_number] => 301 ) [5] => Array ( [id] => 19 [firstname] => Marie [sex] => F [groups_id] => 2 [group_number] => 434 )  [6] => Array ( [id] => 19 [firstname] => Marie [sex] => F [groups_id] => 2 [group_number] => 301 ))
```

How can I do this please ?

Comment: Let's have some newlines in those _huge_ array definitions, please!

Answer (score 0):

hi you can refer below link

[Merge Array with duplicate values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5044784/merging-two-arrays-and-keep-duplicate-values)

```
                     OR
```

[array_merge_recursive](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php)

Thanks.+

Answer (score 0):

Use `array_merge`

```
array_merge($arr1, $arr2);
```